Debugging Karate with mvnDebug in vscode doesn't stop on breakpoints in feature files
I'm attempting get debug working for feature files in vscode with Karate 1.5.0.RC3.
The debug session stops at any breakpoints in java files, but not in feature files.
Here's what I'm doing:

run mvnDebug clean test -Dtest=KarateRunner
attach to port 8000 then to 5005

   {
    "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
       {
         "type": "java",
         "name": "Debug Attach 8000",
         "request": "attach",
         "hostName": "localhost",
         "port": 8000
       },
       {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug Attach 5005",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": 5005
      }
     ] 
   }

At this point the debug session stops at the breakpoint I added to the test runner. When I continue, the session finishes without stopping at the breakpoint I added in asdf.feature.

maven:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Any ideas what I'm missing?

You are debugging Maven instead of the Feature...

Debugging Karate feature files requires specific IDE support.
